# How to have fixed width div have hidden overflow equal on both sides of page

Tags: asp.net, html, css, web

In my site design, I need to have a div centered on the page 1280 pixels wide.

The content within the div will be centered and 960px wide to accomodate most browser sizes.

I need the extra width on the outer div to have hidden overflow on the left/right sides evenly so that the div spills outside the viewing window as the browser is resized/gets smaller.

The layout is currently similar to this:

```
<div> //outer div: width 100%
  <div> //inner div: width 1280 pixels wide with background
    <div> //centered content: 960px wide

    </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

In the image above, the darker blue is 1280px wide. The lighter blue is 960px wide, centered on page.

I need the darker blue to overflow(hidden) off of both sides of the screen when the browser is resized..eventually leaving only the lighter blue centered before a horizontal scroll bar appears.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My current problem is that the outer 1280px div will not overflow properly causing the center div to come off of center.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tKtwg/1/

In the fiddle above, you can see that the outer div does not overflow evenly when you decrease the window size.
**Edit 2**
What I want to avoid is the horizontal scroll bar appearing until the 960 wide div is reached. Sorry I should have been more clear

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and make more of an example?

Comment: Can you post a drawing of what you mean?

Comment: overflow:hidden doesn't sound like what you want.  Instead it sounds like you just want the center content to be horizontally centered.

Comment: You really do not need an overflow here at all. The content area is already centered so just let the browser take care of the scroll for you :)

Comment: What I want to avoid is the horizontal scroll bar appearing until the 960 wide div is reached. Sorry I should have been more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body
{
    background-color: #00a2e8;
    width: 100%;
}


.content
{   
    background-color: #99d9ea;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    min-height: 1000px
}
```

Comment: Yes I have that part taken care of...My problem is that the outer div will not overflow even with overflow:hidden

Comment: You really do not need an overflow here at all. The content area is already centered so just let the browser take care of the scroll for you :)

Comment: What I want to avoid is the horizontal scroll bar appearing until the 960 wide div is reached. Sorry I should have been more clear

Comment: I've changed outer width to 100% - try that?

Answer (score 1):

Check this in your browser and this will be at the center and you don't have to specify negative left margin.

You can change the widths according to your needs and it will be displayed in the center.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
body{margin-top:0;}

.Main{
 width:100%;
 background-color:blue;
 margin-top:0;
}

.Outerdiv{
 background-color:orange;
margin-top:0;
 margin-left:auto; 
 margin-right:auto;
 width:1024px;
 height:500px;
}

.Innerdiv{
background-color:green;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;
height:200px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="Main"> 
  <div class="Outerdiv"> 
    <div class="Innerdiv"> 
<p></p>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

margin:auto; will not always center the content. Explicitly mentioning the values of left margin and right margin to auto then they will be displayed in the center.

Answer (score 1):

How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/JGJBG/2/

```
.main{width: 100%; background-color:red; overflow: hidden; height: 100%;}

.outer
{
    width:1280px;
    background-color:aqua;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
    min-height: 100%;    
}

.center
{
    width:960px;
    position:absolute;  
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    background-color: blue;    
    min-height: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: This is the exact behavior that I am after. I think my problem lies somewhere else. In reality the content that I am trying to center as the 1280px section is a jQuery AnythingSlider plugin, rotating multiple images with html content centered on them

Comment: So .outer = image background that doesn't have to be fully shown, but .center has text? Should there be scrollbars if the window is smaller than 960px (but not if it's > 960px)?